# How to split a large CSV file into multiple JSON files using the Miller command line tool?

Tags: miller

I am currently using this [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) command to convert a CSV file into a JSON array file:

`mlr --icsv --ojson --jlistwrap cat sample.csv > sample.json`

It works fine, but the JSON array is too large.

**Can Miller split the output into many smaller JSON files of `X` rows each?**

For example if the original CSV has 100 rows, can I modify the command to output 10 JSON Array files, with each JSON array holding 10 converted CSV rows?

**Bonus points if each JSON Array can also be wrapped like this:**

```
{
  "instances": 

//JSON ARRAY GOES HERE

}
```

Comment: Did you try my answer? Does it work?

Comment: @aborruso sorry my needs changed so I no longer require a solution to this problem and forgot I asked this, but I have now accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could run this

```
mlr --c2j --jlistwrap put -q '
  begin {
    @batch_size = 1000;
  }
  index = int(floor((NR-1) / @batch_size));
  label = fmtnum(index,"%04d");
  filename = "part-".label.".json";
  tee > filename, $*
' ./input.csv
```

You will have a file named `part-00xx` every 1000 record.